# SIRS model with Agents on NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, eon

I want to simulate and visualize a SIRS model on a NetworkX graph (where a recovered/removed node can again become susceptible). Each node also operates as an agent, and can at each time step, choose to isolate with a probability p, and thus be unable to become infected in that timestep.

I have simulated a SIRS model with EoN.Gillespie_simple_contagion and I am trying to understand if I can modify these methods to include the agent behavior, or if I need to write a bespoke method.

Ive seen its possible to modify some EoN methods: [Modified SIR model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56927079/modified-sir-model)

Here is the code I am using:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import EoN
from collections import defaultdict

# parameters required for the SIRS model
a = 0.1
b = 0.01
y = 0.001
d = 0.001

# Simple contagions
# the below is based on an example of a SEIR disease (there is an exposed state before becoming infectious)
# from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.02436.pdf

Gnp = nx.gnp_random_graph(500, 0.005)

H = nx.DiGraph() #For the spontaneous transitions
H.add_edge('I', 'R', rate = b)  # an infected node can be recovered/removed
H.add_edge('I', 'S', rate = y)  # an infected node can become susceptible again
H.add_edge('R', 'S', rate = d)  # a recovered node can become suscepticle again

J = nx.DiGraph() #for the induced transitions
J.add_edge(('I', 'S'),('I', 'I'), rate = a)  # a susceptible node can become infected from a neighbour
IC = defaultdict(lambda: 'S')

# set all statuses except one to susceptible. only one node shall begin infected
for node in range(500):
    IC[node] = 'S'
IC[0] = 'I'

return_statuses = ('S', 'I', 'R')
print('doing Gillespie simulation')

t, S, I, R = EoN.Gillespie_simple_contagion(Gnp, H, J, IC, return_statuses, tmax = 500)

print('done with simulation, now plotting')
plt.plot(t, S, label = 'Susceptible')
plt.plot(t, I, label = 'Infected')
plt.plot(t, R, label = 'Recovered')
plt.xlabel('$t$')
plt.ylabel('Number of nodes')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes - this is possible.  For the spontaneous transitions you'll want a link from 'S' to 'Isolated' and back.  You'll want to be careful about the use of the idea "time step", because this algorithm does continuous time.  So if you want discrete time, it's more difficult.  - I'll try to give an answer soon, but got to put my daughter to sleep.  If I don't respond later, reply to this message to remind me (or put a note on the EoN github page).

Comment: hi Joel, thanks for the response and the code alteration. 

I should explain a bit more about the 'agent behaviour' i am trying to model. Isolation is not a state, its a seperate network behaviour - so a node could still be S, I or R and also be isolated. I think I may have to try bespoke since I am trying to use discrete time.

Comment: Hi Chebu:  For the continuous version, it wouldn't be hard to have `'isolated_S'`, `'isolated_I'`, and `'isolated_R'` states which do not interact.  For discrete, this is doable, but the reason I haven't done it is that it becomes very hard to think about what happens if multiple things happen at the same time.  What is the timescale you need to do this over?  I may be able to create some code that would do what you want, but it would take time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I will have a play around with it and see if I can detangle all the interactions. Maybe I can add one at a time - no need to write any code, your advice is more than enough

Answer (score 0):

To do this we will introduce a new node status `'X'` to denote the susceptible isolating node.  I've added an edge from `'S'` to `'X'` and another from `'X'` to `'S'` in `'H'`.  I've added `'X'` to the `return_statuses`, and I've plotted it.

To simplify your code, I have removed the loop that assigned everything to initially be `'S'`.  Because it uses a `default_dict` it all starts out as `'S'` implicitly.

You mention the next "time step" and shifting with probability `p`.  This isn't what will happen in this code.  The code works in continuous time.  So it will need a rate.  It doesn't specify exactly how long a node remains isolated, but rather gives an idea of how likely it is to leave at any moment.  If this doesn't make sense to you, you should read up a little bit on the exponential distribution.

Although I haven't used it here, you may want to be aware that EoN comes with tools that allow you to [animate the simulation](https://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html#visualizing-or-animating-disease-spread).

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import EoN
from collections import defaultdict

a = 0.1
b = 0.01
y = 0.001
d = 0.001
to_isolation_rate = 0.05
from_isolation_rate = 1

# Simple contagions
# the below is based on an example of a SEIR disease (there is an exposed state before becoming infectious)
# from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.02436.pdf

Gnp = nx.gnp_random_graph(500, 0.005)

H = nx.DiGraph() #For the spontaneous transitions
H.add_edge('I', 'R', rate = b)  # an infected node can be recovered/removed
H.add_edge('I', 'S', rate = y)  # an infected node can become susceptible again
H.add_edge('R', 'S', rate = d)  # a recovered node can become suscepticle again
H.add_edge('S', 'X', rate = to_isolation_rate)
H.add_edge('X', 'S', rate = from_isolation_rate)

J = nx.DiGraph() #for the induced transitions
J.add_edge(('I', 'S'),('I', 'I'), rate = a)  # a susceptible node can become infected from a neighbour
IC = defaultdict(lambda: 'S')

IC[0] = 'I'

return_statuses = ('S', 'I', 'R', 'X')
print('doing Gillespie simulation')

t, S, I, R, X = EoN.Gillespie_simple_contagion(Gnp, H, J, IC, return_statuses, tmax = 500)

print('done with simulation, now plotting')
plt.plot(t, S, label = 'Susceptible')
plt.plot(t, I, label = 'Infected')
plt.plot(t, R, label = 'Recovered')
plt.plot(t, X, label = 'Isolating')
plt.xlabel('$t$')
plt.ylabel('Number of nodes')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to write a bespoke method for the desired functionality:

```
def SIRS_simulation_with_quarantine(graph, params, tmax):
    a, b, y, d, q = params
    t=0
    graph_current_timestep = graph.copy()
    graph_previous_timestep = graph.copy()
    Infected_nodes = [x for x in graph_current_timestep.nodes() if graph_current_timestep.nodes[x]['state'][0]=='I']
    S = []
    I = []
    R = []
    T = []
    
    while(t<tmax):
        
        for node in graph.nodes():
            
            # initialise random probablilty for that node
            p = np.random.rand()
            # determine neighbours for that node
            neighbors = [n for n in graph_previous_timestep.neighbors(node)]
            
            # depending on the state, check for any state changes and update node attributes
            if graph_previous_timestep.nodes[node]['state'][0] == 'S':
                if (q >  np.random.rand()):                                             # if the node didnt quarantine...
                    if len(set.intersection(set(neighbors), set(Infected_nodes)))>0:    # if any neighbors are infected...
                        if (p < a):                                                     
                            attrs = {node: {'state': 'I'}}
                            nx.set_node_attributes(graph_current_timestep, attrs)                   
            elif graph_previous_timestep.nodes[node]['state'][0] == 'I':                
                if (p < b):
                    attrs = {node: {'state': 'R'}}
                    nx.set_node_attributes(graph_current_timestep, attrs)                    
                elif (p < y):
                    attrs = {node: {'state': 'S'}}
                    nx.set_node_attributes(graph_current_timestep, attrs)

            elif graph_previous_timestep.nodes[node]['state'][0] == 'R':                
                if (p < d):
                    attrs = {node: {'state': 'S'}}
                    nx.set_node_attributes(graph_current_timestep, attrs)

        # after the changes to states have occured for all nodes, record number of nodes at each state, increment timestep
        Infected_nodes = [x for x in graph_current_timestep.nodes() if graph_current_timestep.nodes[x]['state'][0]=='I']
        S.append(len([x for x in graph_current_timestep.nodes() if graph_current_timestep.nodes[x]['state'][0]=='S']))
        I.append(len(Infected_nodes))
        R.append(len([x for x in graph_current_timestep.nodes() if graph_current_timestep.nodes[x]['state'][0]=='R']))
        T.append(t)      
        graph_previous_timestep = graph_current_timestep.copy()
        t = t+1
    
    return T, S, I, R
```